# Solve functional equation $f(x)+f(y)=f(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Tags: trigonometry, continuity, functional-equations

**Abstract**

I have viewed this questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811680/solution-of-the-functional-equation-fx-fy-f-leftx-sqrt1-y2-y-sqrt1?noredirect=1), in which the author asked to prove that $f(4x^3-3x)+f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Scanning through the comments, I saw one trying to figure out the general solution, which suggests that
\begin{align}
f(x)=C\times \arcsin(x)
\end{align}
But no answer was proposed, so I suggest the following problem:

**Problem**

Find the continuous function $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
\begin{align}
f(x)+f(y)=f(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})
\end{align}

**Approach**

My initial idea was to use the Cauchy functional equation schemes to expand the condition suggested in the abstract. But no solution has been yielded.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: There's already an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2815196/229831) to what you've asked (even without the assumption of $ f $ being continuous) under the same [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2811680/229831) you've given a link to.

Comment: In my opinion, this post should be considered a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution of the functional equation $f(x) + f(y) =f\left(x\sqrt{1-y^2 }+y\sqrt{1-x^2 }\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2811680/229831)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=y=0\;\Longrightarrow\;f(0) = 0$

$x=y=1\;\Longrightarrow\;2f(1) = f(0) = 0\;\Longrightarrow\;f(1)=0$

$x=\sin t,\,y=\cos t\;\Longrightarrow\;f(\sin t)+f(\cos t) = f(1) = 0$

$x=y=\cos t\;\Longrightarrow\;2f(\cos t) = f(2\sin t\cos t)$

$x=y=\sin t\;\Longrightarrow\;2f(\sin t) = f(2\sin t\cos t)$

Hence, $f(\sin t) = f(\cos t) = -f(\sin t)$ and so the only solution is $f=0$.

Comment: Seems like the continuity was not even needed...